# swift: avfoundation to capture images

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

i basically have two UIImages. One called previewImage that displays what the AVFoundation Camera displays, and captureImage that displays the image taken using the camera. When I had:

previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize

the two images displayed the same formatting, but when I changed it to:

previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

it seems that the previewImage is horizontally flattened. Is there a way to adjust the captureImage UIImage so that it displays what the previewImage displays through the video feed?[Part of code that assigns image to imageView UIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IavMS.png)

Comment: Images of code never work well; please edit your question and paste the actual code there.